# How to port a existing laravel project on TALL stack to filament

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I have a project already prebuilt on TALL stack. Not too big - around 10 models.. and related crud routes.
How can i move it to Filament? I would like to move it to filament for better meaintenance and scale.

I tried to recreate the roots but some dependencies are not getting registered.